# Silverlight implementation of Flare

Tags: silverlight, flare

Does anyone know of a Silverlight port of the [Flare framework](http://flare.prefuse.org/)?

Google turned up nothing but I wouldn't be surprised if someone somewhere is porting this?

Answer (score 1):

You have an open source charting framework for Silverlight named VISIfire.

Link here : http://www.visifire.com

Comment: Thanks, but the provided link looks like just another charting framework. The interesting part of flare (for me) are the other data visualisations - specifically things like the tree layout visualisations and the doi views with the nifty animations.